# beamer and verbatim

Tags: beamer, verbatim, fragile

why the following mwe doesn't work, if i uncomment line `\end{frame}`?

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,handout,svgnames,table}]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Test uporabe paketa "xcolor"}
\begin{verbatim}
    \documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,handout,svgnames,table}]{beamer}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]{Test uporabe paketa "xcolor"}
        \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{DarkMagenta}\color{white}}c % svgnames
                    >{\columncolor{Apricot}}c}                 % dvipsnames
    aaa & bbb   \\
    ccc & ddd   \\
    \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
%    \end{frame}      % <---
    \end{document}
\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

i obtain error:

```
Runaway argument?
    \documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,handout,svgnames,table}]{b
! File ended while scaning use of \@xverbatim
```

i use recent `beamer`.

log file (first and last few lines from 1411)

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6650 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.4.7)  8 APR 2018 22:39
entering extended mode
**C:/Users/Zarko/Downloads/LaTeX-SE/beamer/beamer-xcolor.tex
(C:/Users/Zarko/Downloads/LaTeX-SE/beamer/beamer-xcolor.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 21 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamer.cls"
Document Class: beamer 2018/02/20 v3.50 A class for typesetting presentations
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasemodes.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2018/02/11 v2.5e e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count79
)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 21.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `beamer-xcolor.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
! You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode.
\enddocument ...cumenthook \deadcycles \z@ \@@end 

l.21     \end{document}

? 

! LaTeX Error: \begin{beamer@frameslide} on input line 20 ended by \end{documen
t}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.21     \end{document}

? 
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.21     \end{document}

? 

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.22     \end{verbatim}

? 

! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{verbatim}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.22     \end{verbatim}

? 
! Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 

l.22     \end{verbatim}

? 
! Emergency stop.
<recently read> \endgroup 

l.22     \end{verbatim}

End of file on the terminal!


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 17140 strings out of 494605
 319476 string characters out of 3168337
 399027 words of memory out of 3000000
 20120 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 5020 words of font info for 19 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 390 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 56i,5n,55p,852b,317s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Which beamer version do you have?

Comment: @samcarter, i use 3.50. interestingly the same mwe was work year ago ...

Comment: I also used `Document Class: beamer 2018/02/20 v3.50 A class for typesetting presentations`. Which engine? I used pdflatex.

Comment: It's also working for me, with or without commenting the `\end{frame}` with beamer v3.48 pdflatex and miktex

Comment: @Zarko do you use miktex or texlive?

Comment: pdflatex, on 64-bit MikteX (upgraded yesterday) ...

Comment: @Zarko Maybe I have a suspicion. Can you add the .log file? I'd like to compare it with mine

Comment: huh, log file is 1500 lines long, for start i will add last lines which deal with error

Comment: add `\listfiles` and then just show the file list from the end of the log.

Comment: I can confirm on: pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) the problem. And the error is: 
"Runaway argument?
^^M    \documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,handout,svgnames,table}]{bea\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.19     \end{frame}"

Comment: Also, any non-empty character in the specific line solves the problem (before or after the command)... So, for them who didn't manage to reproduce, try to leave just an "\end{frame}" there with no additional characters... (The "arrow comment" solves the problem by its own)

Comment: Just checked, the above example also works fine for texlive2018 pretest

Comment: @Zarko Out of curiosity: do you still experience this problem?

Comment: @samcarter, nop. with `beamer 2018/08/22 v3.51` now works as i expected! it seems that this version fix the problem. just now i upgrade my `latex` installation to recent version (v3.52) available in `miktex` and with it still works! . you should reopen answer and tel, that this was seems to be a bug, which is resolved after version v3.51.

Comment: @Zarko Good to hear that it is working now! I'll write a short community wiki answer.

Comment: @samcarter, thank you for your answer! i accept it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem no longer exist in beamer version 3.51 or later.

Where possible, you should [update your TeX
distribution](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) to install the
current release. If this is not possible, for example if you want to
change only this one package or where you do not have the privileges
to update the entire distribution, you will need to [install the
package locally](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137).  This option should be considered a last resort, since for more complex packages there may be package dependencies that will make local installation more complicated and error-prone.